# Trying to make sure it deletes from row 73 down

Tags: vba

```
Sub DelLastRow()
Worksheets(CTDs).Select
Range("A1:Z72").End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).ClearContents
End Sub
```

I get the error subscription out of range

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely coming from the range. You are selecting the range("A1:z72") but then you are clearing the contents of seleciton and then selection.end(xlRoRight).

Change

```
Range("A1:Z72").End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).ClearContents
```

to 
    Range("A1:Z72").End(xlDown).ClearContents

As you the

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))
```

Is not a correct range. It is saying something like

```
Range("A1:Z72","Z72").
```

It makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
    range(rows(73), rows(73).end(xlDown)).ClearContents
```

Or more directly:

```
    [73:1048576].ClearContents
```